# Unit testing using ControllerUnitTestCase in Grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I have the following controller:

```
class MyController {
   def simple = {
      render "simple"
   }
}
```

An respectively the following test case:

```
class MyControllerTests extends ControllerUnitTestCase {
   void testSimple() {
      controller.simple
      def body = controller.response.contentAsString
      assertEquals "simple", body
   }
}
```

I would have expected this test to pass successfully. Surprisingly, it fails with the following result:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: null expected:<[simple]> but was:<[]>
```

I have run the application through the browser and works as expected (i.e. prints "simple).

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I think your test should look like this:

```
   void testSimple() {
      controller.simple()
      def body = controller.response.contentAsString
      assertEquals "simple", body
   }
```

You need to call the simple action(closure).

See here for more: http://www.gitshah.com/2010/04/unit-testing-grails-controller-part-1.html

Thanks,

Jim.